# Combining 2 .unlike .csv files into a new. Coding Challenge

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I am in a coding challenge I have to join content from two cvs files with different headers and output to a new Solution.cvs with all the tricks to stump one up i am struggling and need any help. when i try to run the program i get this error. and when i try to iterate over results i get the following.

**error**

```
CsvHelper.WriterException: 'An unexpected error occurred.
IWriter state:
   Row: 2
   Index: 0
   HeaderRecord:
```

**iterate over results**
gives me this line

```
> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[FeatureApp.OurData]
```

## **OurData.csv**

```
id,name,TrackingID
4563,chevy,Null
3453,toyo,_BL12D9ECFA3AB__
3432,wa,
3453,ford,Null
```

### **TheirData.Csv**

```
Creative,Clicks,Impressions,DateStamp
3453_toyo_Cimbaci_ManMarketing_3.2.16_300x250 Bannerlink_BL12D9ECFA3AB__,0,1432,2/4/2017
35953_Crap Motorsports_5.16.16_300x250 Bake,2,435,4/6/2019
```

as you can see ourdata has null and empty amounts under trackingID which is the linking value between the two pages. and the tracking ID in theirdata is found at the end of the creative string if present

**Program**

```
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace FeatureApp
{
        public class OurData
        {
            [Name("id")]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [Name("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [Name("TrackingID")]
            public string TrackingID { get; set; }
        }
        public class TheirData
        {
            public string Creative { get; set; }
            public int Clicks { get; set; }
            public int Impressions { get; set; }
            public string DateStamp { get; set; }
        }
    class Program
    {


        static void Main()
        {
        IEnumerable<OurData> ourData;
        IEnumerable<TheirData> theirData;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"../../../OurData.csv"))
        
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                ourData = csv.GetRecords<OurData>();
            }

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"../../../TheirData.csv"))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                theirData = csv.GetRecords<TheirData>();
            }

            var results = ourData.Where(s => theirData.Any(i => i.Creative.EndsWith(s.TrackingID)));

            using(var writer = new StreamWriter(@"../../../Solution.csv"))
                using(var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csv.WriteRecords(results);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

---

Any Help Would be greatly appreciated even if its just pointing me to good resources for what i am trying to accomplish. Thanks

Comment: Please edit your post and clarify your question.  Are you getting an error?  Not getting the results you expect?  Or what?

Comment: hopefully my edits help basically it doesnt work and i am kind of lost whats causing the break